# How to set a countdown timer to a specific times in a day using kotlin or java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, timer

I am making an app where it has 5 specific times using this [library](http://praytimes.org/code/) (java file)  in a day to countdown it from the current time I am having, everything works perfectly but whenever I run the code it always throws this error on the logcat and my app shuts down on its own `java. text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "3:28 am"` I don' know what to do if anyone knows how to fix this error it would be a huge help for me.

**Main Activity code**

```
val TimeId = TimezoneMapper.latLngToTimezoneString(
                        location.latitude,
                        location.longitude
                    )

                    val gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeId).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)

                    val z1 = gmt.substring(4)
                    val z = z1.replace(":", ".")
                    val zo = z.toDouble()
                    val latitude: Double = location.latitude
                    val longitude: Double = location.longitude

                    val locationPref = getSharedPreferences("location", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    val editor = locationPref.edit()
                    //    editor.putFloat("lat", lat1.toFloat())
                    //   editor.putFloat("lng", lng.toFloat())
                    locationPref.edit().putDouble("latt1", latitude).apply()
                    locationPref.edit().putDouble("lngg2", longitude).apply()

                    editor.apply()




                    val timeZoneId = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()
                    val prayTime = praytime()
                    prayTime.timeFormat = prayTime.time12 // getTime12 is protected
                    prayTime.calcMethod = prayTime.makkah // Makkah
                    prayTime.asrJuristic = prayTime.shafii // Shafii (standard)
                    prayTime.adjustHighLats = prayTime.angleBased
                    // my codes
                    prayTime.timeZone = prayTime.timeZone1
                    prayTime.setFajrAngle(18.5)

                    prayTime.computeMidDay(prayTime.dhuhrMinutes.toDouble())
                    val offsets = intArrayOf(
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ) // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}

                    prayTime.tune(offsets)
                    val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId.toString()))
                    val now = Date()
                    cal.time = now



                    val times: ArrayList<String> =
                        prayTime.getPrayerTimes(
                            cal, latitude, longitude, zo
                        )
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Fajr).text = times.get(0)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sabah).text = times.get(1)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dhuhr).text = times.get(2)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.AzanTime).text = times.get(3)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maghreb).text = times.get(4)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Esha).text = times.get(6)

                    // this is where I call the timer
                    
                    val diff = getDiffinSeconds(times[0])
                    Thread { countDown(diff) }.start()

                    SalahCount.text = "Time left : $diff hours"

                }
  // countdown timer
private fun countDown(timeRemained: Int) {
    var timeRemained = timeRemained
    while (timeRemained > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        System.out.println("dddddddddddddd")
        System.out.println(getTimeString(timeRemained))
        timeRemained--
    }
}
private fun getDiffinSeconds(praytime: String): Int {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyy hh:mm aa")
    val difInMillis = Math.abs(Date().time - sdf.parse(praytime).time)
    return TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(
        difInMillis,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    ).toInt()
}
private fun getTimeString(sec: Int): String {
    val hours = sec / 3600
    val minutes = sec % 3600 / 60
    val seconds = sec / 60
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you think that your `time` is in this format `SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyy hh:mm aa")` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I used this format also ("hh:mm aa") and it's also gives me the same error